# How can i edit a background based on the h3 content inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.package {
  border: var(--border);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  background: var(--color-bg-900);
  padding: var(--spacing-grid) 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.package h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 0 var(--spacing-xs) var(--spacing-grid);
}
```

```html
<div class="package">
  <div class="package__info">
    <h3>Bl4ckGift</h3>
    <div class="package__tags">
      <span class="tag tag--left tag--700">10.00 EUR</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  # another content here
</div>
```

I need to change the `background` CSS flag, if the `<h3>` tag has `Bl4ckGift` as specific content inside the `<div class="package__info>` class. And my question is, how can I change the background for the `package` class if the `<h3>` tag has specific content? I know how I can change backgrounds, but because it's my first time I work with CSS, I have no clue how I can find the specific package with the `Bl4ckGift` content inside the `<h3>` tag. What would be the best way to change the background for this specific package? I don't know how I can do it with javascript either. I'd like a solution for this, to learn from it.

I'm not very sure how I can describe this problem, not even in my mother language. I hope you guys still understand what I mean and what I need. Feel free to edit the post, if you can explain it better.

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript to look at the text content to find the text you are interested in and then use JS to set the class which has the new background setting. It can't be done purely by CSS as CSS doesn't 'know' about that sort of content.

Comment: You could also use `data-` attributes, and do it with pure CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to check the content of the `h3` element, and then set the background accordingly.

```js
const package = document.querySelector(".package");
const h3 = document.querySelector(".package__info h3");

if (h3.innerText === "Bl4ckGift") {
  package.style.background = "red";
}
```

```css
.package {
  border: var(--border);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  background: var(--color-bg-900);
  padding: var(--spacing-grid) 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.package h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 0 var(--spacing-xs) var(--spacing-grid);
}
```

```html
<div class="package">
  <div class="package__info">
    <h3>Bl4ckGift</h3>
    <div class="package__tags">
      <span class="tag tag--left tag--700">10.00 EUR</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...other content here
</div>.
```

Comment: I need to change the background for `<div class="package">` how can i do it? Just `.package.background = "red"` ?

Comment: Please review my edit.

Comment: @MichaelHaddad sorry about the `==`, that was an accident.